# Single-row subquery returns more than one row - Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

My following code returns the error stated in the title, however the error does not show when the case statement is ran by itself.

I've tried to dismantle the case statement, however this isn't my query but IS being used elsewhere, i'm wondering how they manage to get it to return rows in its current state.

```
SELECT DISTINCT V55."INPUTSPECNAME",
                V55."FKMATERIAL",
                V55."INPUTQUANTITYVALUE",
                B.ABBREVIATION,
                (CASE
                   WHEN z.COST IS NULL
                     THEN (SELECT DISTINCT (CASE
                                              WHEN MatOut_D.PERVALUEQUANTITY > 0 THEN
                                                ROUND(MatOut_D.PRICE / 
                                                      MatOut_D.PERVALUEQUANTITY /
                                                      10 /
                                                      MatOut_E.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR *
                                                      C.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR, 5)
                                              ELSE 0
                                            END)
                             FROM V55_FORMULATIONJOINMATOUTPUT MatOut_B,
                                  V55_FORMULATIONINPUTOUTPUT MatOut_C,
                                  THEORETICALCOSTS MatOut_D,
                                  COMMONCURRENCIES MatOut_E,
                                  UOMML MatOut_F
                             WHERE MatOut_B.FKREFERENCEDMATERIAL = V55.FKMATERIAL
                               AND MatOut_B.FKOWNER = MatOut_C.FKOWNER
                               AND MatOut_C.FORMULATIONOUTPUTPKID = MatOut_D.FKPARENT
                               AND MatOut_D.FKCURRENCY = MatOut_E.PKID
                               AND MatOut_D.FKPERVALUEUOM = MatOut_F.FKUOM
                               AND MatOut_F.LANGID = 0)
                   ELSE ROUND(z.COST*100/D.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR*C.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR,5)
                 END) AS  COST_100G
  FROM V55_FORMULATIONINPUTOUTPUT V55
  INNER JOIN UOM A 
    on V55.FKINPUTUOM = A.PKID
  INNER JOIN UOMML B 
    on a.pkid = B.FKUOM
  INNER JOIN DWBSpecificationRoots dwbRoot 
    on dwbRoot.fkOwner = V55.FKOWNER
  INNER JOIN dwbSpecifications dwbSpec 
    ON dwbSpec.fkWorkingVersionParent = dwbRoot.pkid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN specLegacySpecJoin y 
    on dwbSpec.fkdisplayedlegacyprofile = y.fklegacyprofileid 
       and y.fkspecid = V55.fkMaterial
  LEFT OUTER join COSTITEMS z   
    on z.equivalent = y.equivalent 
      and z.fklegacyprofile = dwbSpec.fkdisplayedlegacyprofile 
      and z.FKSCRMENTITY = dwbSpec.FKSCRMSUPPLIERBASE 
      and z.COSTTYPE = dwbSpec.COSTTYPE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMONCURRENCIES C 
    ON C.PKID = dwbSpec.FKCURRENCY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMONCURRENCIES D 
    ON D.PKID = Z.FKCURRENCY
```

Comment: We can't really help you refactor this, because the query is too complex and we have no sample data.  But, the solution you probably want here is to eliminate that subquery completely, and maybe replace it with a join.

Comment: I understand that, but my main problem is that when i remove the first couple of selects on the first line, the case statement runs fine, so the problem cannot be within the case statement?

Comment: This isn't the way to get help here.  You need to give us a more minimal question.  I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I understand Tim, My question in the simplest form is why does this error occur when both the case statement and standard selects work fine alone, but when selected together produce errors?

Comment: The issue is that every entry in your `SELECT` clause has to be a _scalar_ value.  That is, it needs to be a single value.  The subquery, as it is written now, sometimes returns _more_ than one value.  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In this case, limiting the case statement to 1 row would make it work every time?

Comment: Yes, using `SELECT TOP 1 ...` _might_ fix that error, but the thing is, then you need to figure out which `ORDER BY` clause to use.  That is, you need to figure out the logic for deciding which of the many values to choose.  This query has a smell, so I recommend that you figure out what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Okay, that's given me a good starting point. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the subquery in your CASE statement is returning multiple rows in some situations and as has been stated in the question's comments that's a no-no.

I suggest that you pull the subquery out of the CASE statement and make it a Common Table Expression, then join it into the query as you would any other table:

```
WITH cteSubexpr AS (SELECT DISTINCT MatOut_B.FKREFERENCEDMATERIAL,
                                    (CASE
                                       WHEN MatOut_D.PERVALUEQUANTITY > 0 THEN
                                         ROUND(MatOut_D.PRICE / 
                                               MatOut_D.PERVALUEQUANTITY /
                                               10 /
                                               MatOut_E.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR *
                                               C.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR, 5)
                                       ELSE 0
                                     END) AS CALC_QTY
                      FROM V55_FORMULATIONJOINMATOUTPUT MatOut_B
                      INNER JOIN V55_FORMULATIONINPUTOUTPUT MatOut_C
                        ON MatOut_C.FKOWNER = MatOut_B.FKOWNER
                      INNER JOIN THEORETICALCOSTS MatOut_D
                        ON MatOut_D.FKPARENT = MatOut_C.FORMULATIONOUTPUTPKID
                      INNER JOIN COMMONCURRENCIES MatOut_E
                        ON MatOut_E.PKID = MatOut_D.FKCURRENCY
                      INNER JOIN UOMML MatOut_F
                        ON MatOut_F.FKUOM = MatOut_D.FKPERVALUEUOM
                      WHERE MatOut_F.LANGID = 0)
SELECT DISTINCT V55.INPUTSPECNAME,
                V55.FKMATERIAL,
                V55.INPUTQUANTITYVALUE,
                B.ABBREVIATION,
                (CASE
                   WHEN z.COST IS NULL
                     THEN cs.CALC_QTY
                   ELSE ROUND(z.COST * 100 / D.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR * C.USDCONVERSIONFACTOR, 5)
                 END) AS COST_100G
  FROM V55_FORMULATIONINPUTOUTPUT V55
  INNER JOIN cteSubexpr cs
    ON cs.FKREFERENCEDMATERIAL = V55.FKMATERIAL
  INNER JOIN UOM A 
    on V55.FKINPUTUOM = A.PKID
  INNER JOIN UOMML B 
    on a.pkid = B.FKUOM
  INNER JOIN DWBSpecificationRoots dwbRoot 
    on dwbRoot.fkOwner = V55.FKOWNER
  INNER JOIN dwbSpecifications dwbSpec 
    ON dwbSpec.fkWorkingVersionParent = dwbRoot.pkid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN specLegacySpecJoin y 
    on dwbSpec.fkdisplayedlegacyprofile = y.fklegacyprofileid 
       and y.fkspecid = V55.fkMaterial
  LEFT OUTER join COSTITEMS z   
    on z.equivalent = y.equivalent 
      and z.fklegacyprofile = dwbSpec.fkdisplayedlegacyprofile 
      and z.FKSCRMENTITY = dwbSpec.FKSCRMSUPPLIERBASE 
      and z.COSTTYPE = dwbSpec.COSTTYPE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMONCURRENCIES C 
    ON C.PKID = dwbSpec.FKCURRENCY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMONCURRENCIES D 
    ON D.PKID = Z.FKCURRENCY
```

Best of luck.